# DS18B20 not visible

Tags: raspbian, ds18b20

I can't make visible ds18b20 :/

```
w1-gpio
w1-therm
```

Are running and in /etc/modules

Have added to config

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
```

I've got some data like

```
00-580000000000  00-980000000000  00-d80000000000
```

(00-xx and zeros) xx are changing and number of them changes too.
I got resistor 4k7 Ohm like here

[image: ds18b20]
<sub>(source: [reuk.co.uk](http://www.reuk.co.uk/OtherImages/raspberry-pi-ds18b20-connections.jpg))</sub>

Except for using 5V

I have checked wires and they are fine, i got 5V and GND on board, no idea how to check data but cable itself is fine.
I got rpi 2 and connecting to GPIO4 (pin7)
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm no electrician but it seems to me using 5V as a pull-up on a 3.3V GPIO is a very bad idea.

Comment: @goldilocks In this case the 4k7 resistor has probably limited the damage but it is a much better idea to power the DS18B20 from a 3V3 pin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using device tree (as you appear to be doing from the /boot/config.txt entry) the w1-gpio and w1-therm entries are not needed in /etc/modules.

Remove w1-therm and w1-gpio from /etc/modules and reboot.